# Skype window doesn't show on Debian 7.0 with Openbox

Tags: debian, openbox, skype, panel

I'm running Openbox on Debian, and I don't use any panels or docks because I don't really need them.

I installed Skype (from here: http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=debian32), but after starting it via terminal, it's window doesn't show up at all. Why is that?

Comment: Sometimes these issues can be solved by running the program _again_, it might become visible (i.e. un-minimized) then... no idea if this works with Skype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype seems not to display itself by default, or at least by some of my previous settings.

If I run tint2 prior to trying to run Skype, I can see Skype's icon in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Is it even running -> is it showing up in top/ps?

Have you tried to switch windows with alt-tab? I had this issues aswell with openbox and fluxbox back in the day and could mostly solve it this way.